# devexpress onsuccess parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, devexpress

I've been put on a project for work where they use devexpress. For my task I'm trying to run a javascript function when an ajax call is successful, however I don't know where to put the onsuccess parameter.

I know how to do this for ajax.beginform but for devexpress theres a grid view with a bunch of settings.stuff. Any idea where this goes?

I see a settings.CallBackRouteValues, is this where that goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to handle on a client when DevExpress controls finish their callbacks, handle the [ASPxClientGlobalEvents.EndCallback](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebScriptsASPxClientGlobalEvents_EndCallbacktopic) event. To access this event, add the [ASPxGlobalEvents](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxGlobalEventstopic) component onto a form and use its [ClientSideEvents](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGlobalEvents_ClientSideEventstopic).

If you use MVC, there is the [MVCxClientGlobalEvents](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebMVCScriptsMVCxClientGlobalEventstopic) class which is an analog of ASPxClientGlobalEvents.

The CallBackRouteValues property specifies to what controller action method a callback will be sent.