# jQuery.ajaxcomplete check where ajax occurred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an event:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete
```

which works fine. However, I want to check if ajax occurred at a specific location in the document. Is there a way to check which ajax call occurred?

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
 if (???) //code
 else //code
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by `check if ajax occurred at a specific location in the document`?

Comment: well theres ajax everywhere, I don't want the same functionality to run on every ajax call

Comment: Ajax calls are not triggered on specific elements. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/): **"As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxComplete() method should only be attached to document."** Why are you not just adding functionality to the Ajax calls themselves?

Comment: because this is using dev express and I'm confused. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633623/devexpress-onsuccess-parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only way is to define success function for each ajax function like this :

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    success: function(html){
        //if success
    };
});
```